# ActiveRecordMediator.SaveAndFlush locking SQL Server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, nhibernate, activerecord

I am trying to investigate a problem related to .NET ActiveRecord on SQL Server 2008.

We have a base repository class where we have methods defined for Saving and Updating entities, these methods generally call directly onto the ActiveRecordMediator.

We have a particular instance where if we call ActiveRecordMediator.SaveAndFlush on one of our entities and then try to execute a stored proc that reads from the table we just saved the sproc will hang.

Looking at SQL Server the table is locked thus why it cannot be read. So my questions are:

1. Why is my SaveAndFlush locking the table?
2. How can I ensure the locking doesn't occur?

This application is running as an ASP.NET web site so I assume it is maintaining sessions on a request basis, but I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have figured out why this was occurring.

NHibernate when used in our environment will hold a transaction open for the entire request and then finally when the session is disposed will commit the transaction.

Our sproc was not using the same transaction as NHibernate thus why the locking occurred.

I have partially fixed the problem by wrapping my saving of the entity server side in a using

```
using(var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionMode.New))
{
    ActiveRecordMediator.SaveAndFlush(value);
    ts.VoteCommit();
}
```

This way the entity will be saved and committed immediately.